# Linq query needs to select 3 instead of 1

Tags: .net, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-entities

I have a linq query that only selects a top result using Entity Framework.

```
 var countOfArticlesPerCity = db.ArticleViews
       .GroupBy(s => new { s.ArticleID, s.ActualCity })
       .Select(g => new { g.Key.ArticleID, g.Key.ActualCity, Count = g.Count() });

var highestArticleCountPerCity = countOfArticlesPerCity
       .GroupBy(x => x.ActualCity)
       .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(x => x.Count)
       .FirstOrDefault());

var highestArticleCountPerCityWithArticleTitle = db.Articles
       .Join(highestArticleCountPerCity, x => x.ID, p => p.ArticleID, (x, p) => new { x.title, p.ActualCity, p.Count });

foreach (var line in highestArticleCountPerCityWithArticleTitle)
{
     ViewBag.viewedByCity = line.title + ", " + line.ActualCity + " (" + line.Count + ")";
}
```

How would I convert this to select top 3 results?

Comment: Look at the [`Take`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb503062.aspx) method.

Answer (score 1):

You can select 'Top' usind the Take method:

```
 var highestArticleCountPerCityWithArticleTitle = db.Articles
           .Join(highestArticleCountPerCity, x => x.ID, p => p.ArticleID, (x, p) => new { x.title, p.ActualCity, p.Count })
           .Take(3);
```